# Is RFI still a viable attack vector?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

So, I know Remote File Inclusion bugs are practically dead within modern PHP applications since **register_globals** and **allow_url_includes** are disabled by default in php.ini (ever since php5x I believe?) but I'm wondering whether it's still a viable attack affecting other web-based lanuages?

Does anyone know if other server-sided web-based languages are still vulnerable to RFI? If so, which languages, and more importantly, which functions?

I'm talking default configurations here, not obscure edge-cases.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the title you ask if RFI is still a threat (yes it is), and in the body you ask which languages and which functions are vulnerable (this is off-topic). Which one of the two is it?

Comment: I'm asking IF it is still viable, and if so, which languages/functions are vulnerable? How is that off-topic? It's directly related to my question. RFI is no longer viable within PHP if you're using the default configuration... so I'm asking if it's viable in any other web languages, and if so, which langs/functions?

Comment: RFI will never be dead.  Especially in PHP.

Comment: Perl (and ruby) open is vulnerable to command injection, not rfi. Technically it is only RFI if it's a library loading function (include) otherwise it would be a different category of rce or bug (f.ex ssrf)

Comment: @ConorMancone If you're using PHP out-of-the box e.g. with regular settings, then RFI is most certainly dead. Long dead for that matter.

Comment: @wireghoul I knew there was command injection in open(); as it acts as a pipe (of sorts) but I was also under the impression you could remotely include files? I guess I'm mistaken.. just looked it up. Idk why I thought that was the case. I guess you could include them by using curl/wget as part of your command injection payload, but yeah... that doesn't exactly make it RFI, lol.
I'm honestly not sure what made me think open(); calls were vulnerable to RFI. Anyhow, do you have any examples of traditional RFI bugs existing within other web-based languages? Not PHP.

Comment: @MLT Those are strong assumptions which are unlikely to apply to many systems.

Comment: @ConorMancone Any modern system which has PHP installed is not going to be vulnerable to RFI, unless the admin of the system goes out of their way to modify php.ini and enable those values... 
I don't think that's a strong assumption at all. The only PHP-Based systems that are going to be vulnerable to RFI are either systems that are YEARS out of date and simply haven't been updated or maintained, or they're systems in which an admin has modified their php.ini and intentionally enabled those settings...

Comment: @ConorMancone the vast majority of PHP applications are out-of-the-box installations therefore aren't vulnerable. What you're talking about here are obscure edge cases, certainly not the norm.

Answer (score 1):

No it's mostly a dead bug class, requiring weakened configuration to exploit on modern servers as you stated. The I in RFI stands for `include()` and even though it can be exploited through `require()` and the _once variants I suppose it would require these functions to be a RFI bug. Something like `eval(curl_exec($url))` is not an RFI bug, but could be hard to distinguish from a black box perspective.

Comment: Okay, yeah that's what I figured... I knew it was specifically using include(); or require(); -- same goes with LFI. Lots of people tend to get LFI and LFD mixed up, I've noticed. They'll assume that an LFD is a Local File **Inclusion** bug when it's not using an include(); function. I've had to explain countless times to people that LFD != LFI, and that LFI would treat the contents of the included file as an executable whereas LFD would not. 
Anyway, thanks for your response. I figured it was mostly dead, I was just curious as to whether the same behavior existed in any other web-based langs

Comment: Claiming LFD as LFI is my pet peeve

Comment: yup it triggers me for sure. Also, I KNEW I recognized your nick from somewhere... you're the guy I credited within my .htaccess exploitation blog post because I showed some of your examples of .htaccess phishing methods while I covered that particular topic in my post.

Comment: /me waves ... :)